# Log-determinant ordering for sum of positive definite symmetric matrices

Tags: inequality, determinant, order-theory

If, for real positive definite symmetric $A, B, C$,

$$\log\det (A+B) \geq \log\det(A+C)$$

then can it be said that

$$\log\det(B) \geq \log\det(C)?$$

NOTE: A crude form of the reverse is certainly true. That is, if:
$$B \succeq C$$
then
$$\log\det(A+B) \geq \log\det(A+C)$$
However, this does not help with the forward problem.

Comment: Since $\log$ is strictly increasing, you could drop all logarithms, right?

Comment: Indeed. I just wasn't sure it panned out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not even for diagonal matrices. Consider for instance 
$$C = \left[\begin{array}{cc}\sqrt{2}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{2}-1\end{array}\right]$$
$$B = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & \epsilon\end{array}\right]$$
$$A = I.$$

Then 
$$\det(A+B) = 2+2\epsilon \geq 2 = \det(A+C)$$
but
$$\det(B) = \epsilon < 3-2\sqrt{2} = \det(C)$$
for sufficiently small $\epsilon.$